# CSS3 Mask Styling

Tags: css, mask

A while back I came across some code that masked a CSS Element and allowed the mask to have different CSS stylings, e.g. a border and background color. Basically, I have the following mask:

```
-webkit-mask-box-image: url('../images/back_mask.png');
-webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-mask-origin: border;
```

And I want it to have the same styling as the element it is in, as currently it displays as:
[image]

Any help is appreciated, please inform me if you need anything else (I left the styling CSS out on the code above, and just posted all of the code I use for the mask)

Mask Image: http://babblebox.me/ios/images/back_mask.png

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

dynamically alter the webkit values via javascript, back to "inherit" when you want them to match the element's parent styles.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, on the image I provided the mask doesn't have styling even though I gave it styling on the Element, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: ah... sorry, lots of public image sites and media hosts are blocked here at work.